# How to get the ldap groups in Jenkins Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ldap

I'm using the LDAP plugin to configure Ldap in Jenkins.

I would like to add an parameter in my job listing all the ldap groups.

Groovy would be the easiest way to get the ldap goups.

How to use that?

```
Jenkins.instance.securityRealm.loadGroupByGroupname(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to extract all ldap groups from Jenkins instance you should get all existing users and then extract all groups (authorities) for each user. Jenkins stores ldap groups on each user object.

```
def users = User.getAll()
def ldap_groups = [:]

users.each { user ->
  //get all properties for each user
  user.getAllProperties().each { prop ->
    //if prop jenkins.security.LastGrantedAuthoritiesProperty exists
    if (prop.class.canonicalName == "jenkins.security.LastGrantedAuthoritiesProperty") {
      //extract all ldap groups (authorities)
      prop.getAuthorities().each { group ->
        //populate dictionary with groups and users
        if (ldap_groups.containsKey(group)) {
            ldap_groups[group] += [user.getId()]
        } else {
            ldap_groups[group] = [user.getId()]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

//result
ldap_groups.each { g, u ->
    println "Group: " + g
    print "Users:"  
    u.each {
        println "\t" + it
    }
}

println ""
```